# Need slight tweak on already working formula [Break Time Calculation]

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, formulas, array-formulas

I use this formula in cell G1:

```
=ArrayFormula(sum(($A$2:$A=$F2)*($B$2:$B)*($C$2:$C={"Break - END","Break - START"})*{1,-1}))
```

test sheet - [plz take a copy](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17_hOIT1LEBbLWxFhNNJqOgU3bzpm_EjusP22NE4y9Vs/edit#gid=0)

Well u can see the sheet & thts how we are calculating the break time for a person based on the form data submission.

Now thers a slight change. I need the formula to work for the following setup. hoping someone can help me out on where to tweak the formula

I need to make formula in G2 work when the new column is added (column D):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

may be this one:

```
=ArrayFormula(sum(($A$2:$A=$F2)*($B$2:$B)*($C$2:$C&$D$2:$D={ʺBreak - ENDʺ,ʺBreak - STARTʺ})*{1,-1}))
```

Comment: hey thnx for the response.. this one worked.

           =SUM(ArrayFormula((A2:A=F2)*(B2:B)*(if(offset(B2:B,0,1)="Break - START", -1, 1))))